# How to combine three integers into one unique tag, such that the tag stays integer in C++?

Tags: c++, integer, unique

I tried to use Cantor and Szuszik pairing functions, but e.g. a = 200, b=201 c=202
the resulting P(a, b, c) = P(P(a,b),c) it is already a very large number that does not fit into **int**.

Comment: Are there any size limits on the input integers?

Comment: You can't uniquely fit three integers into one integer. There will have to be some tag overlap.

Comment: I believe, the three numbers can be uniquely defined on the interval [0:1000] even though they are of int. So, pairing three numbers that are [0:1000] would be my question

Comment: OK no problem, then.  Writing an answer.

Comment: Carl Norum, as I said for small numbers we already accede the limit: a = 500, b = 200, c = 600 P(Szuszik) = 62 851 744 106. Whereas the limit for int is 2 147 483 647. P(a, b) = (a >= b ? a * a + a + b : a + b * b)

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  Why do you care about these operations?  Your question says you want to combine three integers into a tag.  What does that have to do with pairing functions?

Comment: I am creating a tag for MPI_Send, which is a type of MPI_INT. It could be defined uniquely only that way (at least what I see now)

Comment: Did you read my answer?  It clearly creates a unique output integer for each input triple.

Comment: Carl Norum, oops. Needed to update the page. Sorry. Thank you, I think it is what I need. I will check it already tomorrow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Uniquely combining three numbers in the range [0:1000] is no problem (assuming `int` is 32-bits or larger on your system, that is):

```
int combine(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return (a << 20) | (b << 10) | c;
}
```

To extract them later:

```
void unpack(int combined, int *a, int *b, int *c)
{
    *a = combined >> 20;
    *b = (combined >> 10) & 0x3ff;
    *c = combined & 0x3ff;
}
```

This packing is safe because 1000 is less than 2<sup>10</sup>, so those numbers will always fit in 10 bits.

Comment: You mean [0:1023]?

Comment: OP asked for numbers between 1 and 1000. See comments on question.

Answer (score 2):

You can't uniquely fit three integers into one integer if all ints are of the same size. However, what you can do is fit three smaller integers into one larger integer. For the sake of elegance, I'm going to modify your problem to say that you are trying to pack 4 16-bit integers into 1 64-bit int (having specific requirements makes the solution more clear). You can modify the solution to match your needs:

```
uint16_t a = 61000, b=60000, c=48000, d=32000;
uint64_t e = 0;

memcpy((char*)&e, &a, sizeof(a));
memcpy((char*)&e + (1*sizeof(b)), &b, sizeof(b));
memcpy((char*)&e + (2*sizeof(c)), &c, sizeof(c));
memcpy((char*)&e + (3*sizeof(d)), &d, sizeof(d));
```

EDIT: Here is a cleaner version using bitwise operators and bit-shift (it assumes that each of the ints being packed uses only the least significant 16 bits)

```
uint64_t a = 61000, b=60000, c=48000, d=32000;
uint64_t e = 0;

e = (a << 48) | (b << 32) | (c << 16) | d;
```

Comment: what an elegant, well thought out answer! @2to1mux Stack Overflow can use more fine gentlemen like yourself! Way to go!

Answer (score 1):

In case order of integers is important (so `tag(a,b,c) != tag(b,c,a)`) you need a tag of size `N^3` where `N` is the maximum of input integer. `N^3` - because this is the number of possible triples `(a,b,c)` you can make. Each must map to unique value. So you need your tag to be able to hold value of `N^3`. Mapping can be done as: `a + b * N + c * N^2`