# Combine n integers into a single unique representation

Tags: c++, combinatorics

Similar to this question:
[How to combine three integers into one unique tag, such that the tag stays integer in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697645/how-to-combine-three-integers-into-one-unique-tag-such-that-the-tag-stays-integ)

But for any number of integers?

If we want to narrow it down more, lets say we have 30 integers, each with a value between 0 and 5. Is it possible to define a single integer value that will uniquely define the list of integers?

Comment: The general technique is called [arithmetic coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding).

Comment: Sure, you can store it in a 78 bit integer.

Comment: You can look into unions, can encode your values in 3 bits each probably.

Comment: Do you want only to "uniquely define the list of integers" or you want to retrieve them back ? If first - look at [std::hash](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash)

Comment: An alternative is hashing, if your numbers are larger than 0-5 this can save a lot of space, and getting collisions with e.g. SHA hashes is extremely unlikely.

Comment: @Henrik can you point me to something I can read to understand this? I.E why a 78bit integer and how?

Comment: @jramm You have 6 ^ 30 possible sequences. 6 ^ 30 is a number with 78 binary digits.

Comment: You could do `result = int0 + 6*int1 + 36*int2 + ... + 36845653286788892983296 * int29`. But actually, on almost all platforms, this would overflow.

Answer (score 1):

In general you can combine a number of integers together with multiplying and adding. If `r` is the range of values needed (6 for your example of 0-5) then you can combine them like this:

```
uint64_t sum = 0
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    sum *= r;
    sum += value[i];
}
```

If you try to combine too many values you'll get an overflow. You can predict the number of bits you need in an integer with a simple formula:

```
bits = log(pow(r, n)) / log(2);
```

In your example you need 78 bits. This is more than most integer types can store, so you won't be able to combine all 30 values.

If `r` is a power of 2, you can use bit shifting rather than multiplication. This is slightly more efficient, especially if you need to extract the original values back later. This is why the answers in the linked question all used shifting. If your range `r` is not near a power of 2, this will limit the number of values you can combine.